# How can I fix "Cannot find tnameserv" error trying to run java server program on Textpad?

Tags: java, corba

I have this error regardless of code so I don't think it's necessary, however if it is I will gladly make it available to anyone.
I am trying to make a CORBA Java Server application using Textpad but when I try to run it I get this error saying "cannot find tnameserv". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the tnameserv or orbd that comes with the JRE.